# How to compile a C++ program in Xcode for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, xcode, cross-compiling

I have a simple command line program in C++ that I have written in Xcode, that I want to compile so that it can run in windows. The only libraries I'm using are `#include <iostream>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Do you have a Windows compiler?  Is your question about how to build ON Windows for Windows, or are you trying to cross-compile on the Mac for Windows?

Comment: @mark I have another windows machine beside me I'll send it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross compiler. I recommend GCC with homebrew. https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers